# intalling mongodb on debian 12

Tags: linux, mongodb, debian, apt

I am trying to install mongodb on Debian 12, but it seems that the last supported version of debian is 11 (bullseye), so I can't add the repo correctly before installing mongodb.

Is there anyway to install it on debian 12[image]

Comment: Possibly interesting: [_"Debian 12 meet dependencies for Ubuntu 22.04LTS mongodb-server packages"_](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongo-6-x-on-debian-12/232593/5).

Answer (score 1):

**Warning; Do it at your own risk, I have no idea what security implications may have my computer if I install libssl1.1 from a `.deb`package, I do this at my own risk.**

#### My workaround

*(AFAIK)* MongoDB it is not ready yet for Debian 12 Bookworm, so I entered to [mongodb official website](https://www.mongodb.com) and install it for Debian 11 using the guide from [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Debian](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/), So please be sure of following those step before trying anything else.

#### After installing following the official MongoDB site instructions.

I stumble across this error
`E: Package 'libssl1.1' has no installation candidate`, then I decided to go to the [Debian -- Package download selection for Libssl1.1](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/libssl1.1/download) and pressed on the link (In case you do not find it, [this is the link](http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1n-0+deb10u5_amd64.deb)) and installed libssl1.1 using `dpkg` command.

#### Post libssl1.1 installation.

Please remember to do a `sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/` and create the `/data/db` so you can run MongoDB without problems

#### Footer

I hope this answer suits you (and everyone who read it) well. If someone sees something wrong with this answer, please let me note it, I am not a Debian expertise, so I must insist. **Do this at your own risk**

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB now provides packages for Debian 12 Bookworm at [repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/dists/bookworm/](http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/dists/bookworm/)

Following the installation instructions for Debian 11 "Bullseye" here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/

and changing the line

`echo "deb [ signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian bullseye/mongodb-org/7.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list`

to

`echo "deb [ signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian bookworm/mongodb-org/7.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list`

worked for me to install MongoDB on Debian 12

Comment: Indeed, this works.  Remember to run 'apt update' after this.